# OpenGL: rendering in immediate mode won't interpolate color

Tags: opengl

I was trying to render some quads in immediate mode the other day, and I wanted them to have a nice interpolated color gradient - something like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glColor4f(...red...);
  glVertex3f(...upper left...);

  glColor4f(...red...);
  glVertex3f(...bottom left...);

  glColor4f(...green...);
  glVertex3f(...bottom right...);

  glColor4f(...green...);
  glVertex3f(...upper right...);
glEnd;
```

No luck though. What it does in my case is that it displays the whole quad in the last set color - in this case green. Even if I switch to triangles, it's pretty much the same story. This has never happed to me before, so I'm wondering, what may be the possible cause for it. As far as I know, this can only happen if I was using some badly set shader, but I'm not using any, so I appear to have got it wrong. Bad settings somewhere perhaps?

Comment: try maybe: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml, glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH), or maybe you have lighting enabled...

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to enable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`?

Comment: Actually, I had glShadeModel set to GL_FLAT in some historical section of the code, so I wasn't aware of it. Looking up the call of this function did trick, so thanks.